# Unable to open a windows form during debugging in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, windows

I am debugging a windows application in visual studio 2010, the application was developed and upgraded from .net framework v2 and VS 2005.

Originally, windows forms could be open on debugging mode. However, several times later without editing (as I was just tracking possible bugs before fixing), those forms become unable to open. Whenever, I tracked the bugs until the code which shows the form, then the debugger will just stop tracking without any messages. Does anyone know what problems could cause this situation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: Please post some code showing how you open the forms.

Comment: If not all such Windows applications experience the problem, then you should post more information about your one. If all such Windows applications experience the same problem, then probably you should repair VS.

Comment: Sorry, it is private codes (developed in .netframework v2 and vs2005), not coded by me. I'm only responsible to debug (in .netframework v4 and vs2010) the application; thus, I cannot post the detailed codes. However, I only ran this codes many times to check the problems, the forms could always open...I didn't modify the code, but suddenly, application forms are unable to show out.

Comment: Are these forms in a third party class library?

Comment: Running on a 64-bit operating system?  Seeing a "first chance" exception notification in the Output window?

Comment: Yes, the form were created by using 3rd party class lib.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you are unable to debug step into code then this usually indicates that there is no debug information available due to missing source and/or a missing debug .pdb file for that item.

Check the build configuration to ensure that you are attempting to debug a debug build, it is easy with solutions containing multiple projects to accidentally set the configuration manager to build a project in release mode, whilst the project that you're stepping from is in debug mode.

Also in multi-project solutions check that you are referencing the project and not the project output where required, otherwise setting the configuration manager to build a project in debug mode will have no effect if you're referencing a release build output for that project.

If the Winforms reside in a third party DLL then ensure that you have referenced a debug version of the library before attempting to debug.

Comment: Last time, I rebuilt the solution and re-checked .net framework version in each project, then it worked; but it didn't work for this time, and I restarted my PC, and then it works again......so weird.